# SQL Column Not Found

Tags: sql, foxpro

I'm trying to build a SQL query to cross checks a couple of columns. 
My issue is with the calcontvalue column. 
The query works fine until I want to include a Where clause containing it `AND calcontvalue = job.contvalue`.

```
SELECT 
job.accountno, 
job.groupno, 
job.contvalue, 
job.z1total, 
job.z2equip, 
job.z3freight, 
job.z4pack, 
job.z5ancil, 
job.z6roy, 
job.zrpay, 
job.z7paid, 
job.z8invtype,
IIF(job.z8invtype <> 0, job.z2equip+job.z5ancil, 
IIF(job.z8invtype <> 1, job.z2equip+job.z3freight+job.z4pack+job.z5ancil, 0)) AS calcontvalue, 
group.groupno, 
group.grouptype, 
group.title  FROM job

LEFT JOIN group  
ON job.groupno = group.groupno 
WHERE grouptype = 'J' AND calcontvalue = job.contvalue
```

The I'm presented with this error:

> SQL:Column 'CALCONTVALUE' is not found.

Not sure what to try next.

Comment: The WHERE grouptype = 'J' condition makes the LEFT JOIN execute as a regular INNER JOIN. If you really want a LEFT JOIN result, move that condition to the ON clause. (Otherwise switch to INNER JOIN...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use alias in `WHERE`, use full expression:

```
SELECT 
  job.accountno, 
  job.groupno, 
  job.contvalue, 
  job.z1total, 
  job.z2equip, 
  job.z3freight, 
  job.z4pack, 
  job.z5ancil, 
  job.z6roy, 
  job.zrpay, 
  job.z7paid, 
  job.z8invtype,
  IIF(job.z8invtype <> 0, job.z2equip+job.z5ancil, 
  IIF(job.z8invtype <> 1, job.z2equip+job.z3freight+job.z4pack+job.z5ancil, 0)) AS calcontvalue, 
  group.groupno, 
  group.grouptype, 
  group.title  
FROM job
LEFT JOIN group  
  ON job.groupno = group.groupno 
WHERE grouptype = 'J' 
  AND IIF(job.z8invtype <> 0, job.z2equip+job.z5ancil, 
      IIF(job.z8invtype <> 1, job.z2equip+job.z3freight+job.z4pack+job.z5ancil, 0)) = job.contvalue
```

Also naming table `group` is bad practise because `GROUP` is keyword `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Or a derived table, to save some typing. (If Foxpro supports it.)

Comment: @jarlh Yes, subquery/cte can be used but I don't know Foxpro capabilities so I just use most universal method

Comment: VFP 9 supports derived tables, but not CTEs.

Comment: @TamarE.Granor Good to know. Thanks.